# Google App Engine Webapp2 Remove User

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am using webapp2 basic user authentication system. I succeeded creating users, ensuring they're logged in, changing password and more.
But I just can't understand how to remove a user and revoke it's token so all logged-in sessions with be no longer valid.
Which datastore object except the user itself should I remove?

Comment: What do you mean by "basic user authentication system"?

Comment: @MeLight I've followed this tutorial:
http://blog.abahgat.com/2013/01/07/user-authentication-with-webapp2-on-google-app-engine/

Comment: There's a Logout section in that tutorial. Isn't it working?

Comment: Yeah, but only the current logged in user can log out. I want to revoke a users permission programmatically